# Conditional Citation

Tags: citing, conditionals

I am working on writing a chapter for which I want to control whether citations will appear or not in the end.

Something like a global variable:

```
CITATIONS_APPEAR = TRUE

if TRUE:
   citations will appear
if FALSE:
   citations will not appear
```

In other words, I will write my document as usual using the \cite (or modified \cite) command, but whether the citations will appear or not is governed by CITATIONS_APPEAR.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `\cite` command to `\unskip` when you don't want citations, or set the regular `\cite` when you want. We use [`letltxmacro`](//ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro) to properly store the optional-argument-enabled `\cite` in `\oldcite` and then redefine it to condition via `\ifcitation`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xparse,letltxmacro}

\newif\ifcitation

\LetLtxMacro\oldcite\cite
\RenewDocumentCommand{\cite}{o m}{%
  \ifcitation
    \IfValueTF{#1}
      {\oldcite[#1]{#2}}% \cite[.]{..}
      {\oldcite{#2}}% \cite{..}
  \else
    \unskip
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\chapter{A chapter}

\citationfalse
\noindent Some citation \cite{abc, def}. In \cite[p.~56]{abc} it is mentioned that \ldots

\citationtrue
\noindent Some citation \cite{abc, def}. In \cite[p.~56]{abc} it is mentioned that \ldots

\let\cleardoublepage\relax% Just for this example

\begin{thebibliography}{x}
  \bibitem{abc} Abc.
  \bibitem{def} Def.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse) just provides an easy interface for specifying and condition on the use of optional arguments.